# Datagrid Won't Select Item

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a empty telerik DataGrid and I have a button `Add Row`. 
I have a column "Impact" Which is a combo box and when I select an item from it and select another column with a `DatePicker` it doesn't register the first action.(Selecting an impact) If I choose another column instead of Datepicker it works completely fine and registers the first action.

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Hours"  ItemsSource="{Binding VisJobHours}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding JobHrs}" SelectedValueMemberPath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Impact"  ItemsSource="{Binding VisJobImpacts}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding JobChange}" SelectedValueMemberPath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Realized">
   <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadDatePicker  SelectedValue="{Binding DateRealized, StringFormat=d}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

Just wondering how do I go abouts to fixing this, I hope I explained it well enough. Im thinking something like when mouse away from select row event. Not entire Sure :S

Or `Deselecting` the combo box